# how do I tell a ruby/cucumber test suite to run in parallel on a selenium grid

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir, selenium-grid

Here is the setup:

Local Machine - Hosting the code
Remote Machine - Hosting Jenkins & selenium hub
Remote Machine2 - Running selenium stand-alone in node mode

I have the code setup to hit the hub, and the hub does detect the node, and the code executes on the node just fine.  The problem with this is that the tests are still run in serial.  How do I setup the code so that each cucumber scenario runs in parallel?  (I imagine a queue that when one node opens up that meets the requirement, the next in line gets it)  Here is what I currently have

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
caps = WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(:browser_name => 'chrome', :profile => profile)

@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://#{ENV['TEST_MACHINE']}/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) Ruby gem.

Comment: I like it, however i'm getting an error when I try to run my rake task "Don't know how to build task 'parallel:features'

Comment: So I fixed the rake issue but now I can't get it to run. Cheezy said something about it not working on windows. Any other options? (or ideas on how i can get it to work on windows, or why it doesn't work on windows considering i'm running it on the command line through jruby)